# How to solve Input string was not in correct format in Angular8?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

In my asp.net core 3.1 I have method which I am returning back aws intance type list and I am consuming api in my angular 8 project.

When I use postman I am getting back json result as

```
[
    "c5n.4xlarge",
    "m2.2xlarge",
    "t3.xlarge",
    "m5dn.8xlarge",
    ..........
]
```

But in network tab in chrome I am getting response back

[image: Numbered json result]

And when I try to post (it works in backend) It throws error

**Input string was not in correct format**

I see it does not grab value and sets to undefined. How to make json result similar to postman result not numbered. No idea that is the reason or not. But in response section it is normal json. Maybe it is multiple arrays that is the reason.

P.S. Also looked another topics about Input string was not in correct format but it was related with integer issue but in my case I need just string

My service: // it is also similar method for opentack and it works fine

```
createAws(model: any, projectId: number, instanceType?: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}servers/${projectId}?i 
   instanceType=${instanceType}`, model);
  }
```

My component: //

```
selectInstanceHandler(event: any){
    this.selectedInstance = event.target.value;
  }



createAws(instanceType: any){
    this.subs.add(this.cvmService.createAws(this.model,this.projectId,instanceType).subscribe(
      x => {
        this.model = x;
        this.alertify.success("successfully added new Server");
      },
      error => {
        this.alertify.error("\n" + error);
      }
    ))
  }
```

My html:

```
      <div class="row" *ngIf="type == 'AWS'">
        <div class="col-3 mt-3 labelText">
          <span class="spanText">Aws Instance Type</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <mat-label>Please select intance type</mat-label>
            <select matNativeControl required name="awsInstanceType" 
             [(ngModel)]="model.awsInstanceType"
              (change)="selectInstanceHandler($event)">
              <option value="-1" disabled> </option>
              <option *ngFor="let item of aws">
                {{ item }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Example in postman which works:

```
{{url}}/api/servers/22?instanceType=r5a.large
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not numbered, it is just chrome's way of formatting data to make it easy to read. That is why it is known as preview tab.

Check the response tab, the response is just the array of strings (i.e. not numbered)

Comment: yes I checked it is normal result as postman, but still when I post it sets to undefined and throw Input string was not in correct format.

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov Then post that code with example string. The error has a different cause than you think, it seems.

Comment: @Fildor interesting part it is working in postman without any issue

Comment: where are you trying to post it and how

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov Exactly. So your code does something differently than postman. We need to find out what that is.

Comment: @ShlokNangia I have method also for openstack absoletuly same strategy and it works fine but why this one not grabbing data from dropdown and sets to undefined no idea

Comment: are you getting undefined in this.selectedInstance?

Comment: @ShlokNangia yes but dont know why, cause I am sure I used same approach for openstack and it worked

Comment: try using this.model.awsInstanceType instead of selectedInstance

Comment: @ShlokNangia btw I tried to show in console and I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined**

Comment: put breakpoint in chrome dev tools in function selectInstanceHandler() and check the value of event. there you might not be getting correct event. also as I said use this.model.awsInstanceType and then you might not need selectInstanceHandler

Comment: @ShlokNangja using this.model.awsInstanceType worked

Comment: happy to help :-)